# combining Capybara and Minitest syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, minitest

I installed Capybara and Selenium. I have three tests for the login process:

1. test using Minitest
2. using Capybara
3. combining Minitest and Capybara syntax.

Test 3 raises an failure in the Capybara assertion, "Not at Dashboard".

Is it possible to combine the syntax of Minitest and Capybara within the same test? If yes, what goes wrong in my test 3?

---

1) Minitest:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user_one = users(:dagobert)
    end

    test "login with minitest" do
        # Go to login
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'  

        # Login
        log_in_as(@user_one)
        assert is_logged_in?

        # Assert redirect to dashboard
        assert_redirected_to dashboard_url      
        assert_template 'dashboard/index'
    end
end
```

---

2) Capybara:

```
require "capybara_test_helper"
require 'test_helper'

class UserLoginCapybaraTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user_one = users(:dagobert)
    end

test "login with capybara" do

    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

    # Go to login
    visit "/login"
    assert_equal "/login", current_path
    assert page.has_content?("Log in"), "Not Log in"

    # Login
    fill_in('session_email', :with => @user_one.email)
    fill_in('session_password', :with => 'password')
    click_button "Log in"

    # Assert redirect to dashboard
    assert page.has_content?("Dashboard")
  end
end
```

---

3) Minitest & Capybara combined, gives a failure:

```
require "capybara_test_helper"
require 'test_helper'

class UserLoginCapybaraTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user_one = users(:dagobert)
    end

    test "login with minitest & capybara" do
        # Go to login
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'  

        # Login
        log_in_as(@user_one)
        assert is_logged_in?

        # Assert redirect to dashboard
        assert_redirected_to dashboard_url      
        assert_template 'dashboard/index'

        # Check content with Capybara
        assert page.has_content?("Dashboard"), "Not at Dashboard"
    end
end
```

Comment: There are two or three questions here.  Please ask one question per... er... question.

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer, but take a look at [minitest-rails-capybara](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara).

Comment: Removed question 2. If in the future I want to test functionality that is downstream of the login, is there a way to "fast track" the login process, so not every test requires to go through the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine #get and #page use in one test and expect things to work properly because they both have their own requests and page contents.
  Capybara (when using a JS capable driver) attempts to emulate a user by running a browser and controlling it to make requests to the app. Capybara then queries the document in the browser. You don't (in most capybara drivers) have access to things like response codes, templates rendered, etc because a user wouldn't normally see them, and the purpose of Capybara (again) is to emulate a user.

#get, on the other hand, shortcuts by calling directly to the app.  You can use Capybara provided matchers/asserts on the content of response obtained with #get by using [Capybara.string](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara#string-class_method).

"fast tracking" login is highly dependent on what you're using for authentication and should probably be asked as a separate question with a lot more details about your app